# Python print an element of list checking presence of a partial text - Python 3.5, Windows 7

Tags: list, python-3.x

Suppose I have a list:
l = ["3 Beds", "2 Baths", "4 Rooms"]

What I want is, from this l[i] print that l[i] which contains "Beds" only.

Basically am scrapping lists from a webpage and placing each element of the list in csv. But the problem is not every list is ordered as "Beds", then "Baths" and then "Rooms". Also the list might not have an element. So in those cases, I need to give NaN which I have taken care of. So I want to place "3 Beds" in the "Beds" column only.

Can someone help me with this code?

Comment: Can't you loop in your list and test something like 

    if "Beds" in list_elem

Or even better : if "beds" in list_elem.lower()

Comment: shows me * undefined name "list_elem" *

Comment: Sorry my list is like list = ['3 Beds', '2 Baths', '3 Rooms']. So 3 Beds is not string also.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you loop in your list and test something like

```
if "Beds" in list_elem
```

Or even better :

```
if "beds" in list_elem.lower() 
if "beds" in list_elem.casefold() # only python3
```

?

So something like

```
for list_elem in l:
    if "beds" in list_elem.lower():
         #do stuff
```

Comment: Although it probably doesn't matter in this application, you should use `.casefold()` instead of `.lower()` for case-insensitive comparisons. [reference link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold)

Comment: You need to loop through your list something like

for list_elem in l: